Can a 15-year-old travel alone with an expired Jamaican passport and a valid green card?
My 15-year-old daughter has an expired Jamaican passport and a valid green card. Can she travel alone to Jamaica with the expired passport?

Is she travelling from the US? Timatic states: if departing from the USA (regardless of any destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or accepted departure document is required by the US immigration authorities.

Yes she traveling from the USA

@Traveller I'm fairly certain that the green card is an "accepted departure document" (since it is sufficient by itself for re-entry to the US).  But I'm not certain enough to post this as an answer.

Tricky.
From https://www.pica.gov.jm/immigration/travel-documents-required

Jamaican citizens are required to present the following documents to Immigration:
A valid Jamaican passport, an emergency certificate or an expired Jamaican passport (providing acceptance from the airline)

Airlines are generally reluctant to accept expired passports, so you will have to contact the airline directly and ask. Preferably get their agreement in writing.
This is a complicated travel situation especially for a 15-year old. I would strongly recommend renewing the passport or get an emergency travel certificate from the Jamaican consulate.

TIMATIC does note that an expired Jamaican passport is sufficient.  I don't doubt that it might raise some red flags but all indications suggest that this combination of documents is sufficient, which airline employees should recognize even if some prompting is needed.  I think it unlikely that an airline would give a firm commitment to board anyone on any specific set of documents, however, because they want to avoid a situation where there is some factor that they hadn't considered that arises only at check-in, and then the traveler might accuse them of failing to keep their promise.

All I'm saying that it is a nontrivial risk. It depends a lot on what type of check in agent you are going to get and who good the 15-year is in managing potentially controversial negotiations.

A good point to be sure.  The risk is certainly nontrivial and the recommendation in the last sentence is well made: without knowing more about specific practices related to Jamaican green card holders, it's better to avoid traveling with these documents if possible.
